# Sort alphanumeric dictionary keys based on only numeric part in key

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a dictionary like the one below:

```py
dictionary = {
  "sf_init#12" : "string",
  "sf_code#5" : "string",
  ...
}
```

I want the keys to be sorted in the order:

1. `sf_code#5`
2. `sf_init#12`
3. ...

I tried using `split()` in a `lambda` function and then sorted the numeric part, but it did not work.
Anyone who has a better idea how to sort this?

**(Note) : I am using Python2. Also, I do not want natural sorting.**

Comment: (1) Show your failed code. (2) If you don't want a natural sort, tell us what you *do* want, since your example is consistent with natural sort.  (3) Show example output, especially the expected data type.  Since Python 2 dicts are inherently unsorted, we're not clear what you expect from this effort.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like "natural" sorting. What do you think that is and how is what you want different?

Comment: Why are you using Python 2?

Comment: By natural sorting, I mean if i have a dictionary : sf_code#110 and sf_init#27,  the output should be sf_init#27 and then sf_code#110. You can ignore the alphabets.

Comment: @AMC It is the requirement.

Comment: @tanushree What, which requirements?

Comment: @Prune Shows me an error "Invalid syntax"

Comment: @AMC The entire code is in Python2. I cannot change it.

Comment: @tanushree _Shows me an error "Invalid syntax"_ What does?

Comment: sorted(dictionary, key=lambda k:(k[1],k[0])) sorts by sf_code#5 than sf_init#12 if im understanding it right.

Comment: @aundeep chohan I am getting this output :                                                    
      dicts = {"sf_init#27": 'g', "sf_code#5" :'h'}
      for i in sorted(dicts.keys(), key=lambda k:(k[1], k[0])):
          print (i)                                                                                                                                                         output : sf_init#27
             sf_code#5

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  We also need the *full* error message, including explanatory text: the line number and full message, or the trace-back.

Comment: Also, this information should be edited into the question.  As you can see, comments are *lousy* at showing code.

Comment: You still haven't explained the order you *do* want.  Is it *descending* lexical order on the numeric strings after the octothorpe (hash mark)?

Answer (score 0):

The sort you use in your comments specifies to sort on the 2nd and 1st characters of the keys.  These are `'f', 's'` for both keys.  If you want to sort by the number at the end, you need to extract those.  Try

```
dicts = {"sf_init#27": 'g', "sf_code#5" :'h'}
for i in sorted(dicts.keys(), key=lambda k: k.split('#')[-1], reverse=True):
    print (i)
```

Output

```
sf_code#5
sf_init#27
```